# Recorrer un json con _embedded

Tags: php, json

Tengo un cURL request con la siquiente salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PORT => "8084",
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8084/api/plantas/".$getId."/sensores",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       "Accept: */*",
       "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Cookie: JSESSIONID=4D1E53930AA73A7275B51A5EF28367A7",
                            "Host: localhost:8084",
                            "Postman-Token: b6118a97-d7b9-4d70-917a-14ae844af96d,42b57976-ac62-4ce6-bb5c-a3a0603a3ff8",
                            "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
                            "cache-control: no-cache"
                        ),
                        ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);                        

    $someArray = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach ($someArray as $key => $value ) {
        echo $value["nombre"];
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

    }
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\sensores.php on line 130

Como puedo recorrerlo y quedar solo con "nombre":"sensor1" y luego solo con "sensor1"

Comment: Coloca como texto la salida de tu código por favor y del mismo modo añade lo que lleves al momento aunque tengas errores

Comment: Lo he cambiado.Gracias